# Mantis: What do I change to auto-display attached images when viewing issues?

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking, mantis

I am able to upload images to mantis issues. I'd like to tweak the mantis code or config to auto-display images (gif, png, jpg).

Has anybody been successful in doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is controlled by the `$g_preview_attachments_inline_max_size` variable in config_inc.php

According to the [Mantis manual](https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html/admin.config.uploads.html):

> This feature applies to bmp, jpg, gif,
> and png files that are attached to
> bugs. If the file size is smaller than
> the specified values, the actual image
> is also previewed with the bugs [...]

Although the manual says the default value is 0 (feature disabled), in Mantis 1.2.0 it is 256KBytes:

```
$g_preview_attachments_inline_max_size = 256 * 1024;
```

Comment: I thought it was obvious :)
If you want to disable the behaviour you should edit the config_inc.php and set the $g_preview_attachments_inline_max_size to 0
However, if you want to enable inline preview for larger images, set the $g_preview_attachments_inline_max_size variable to the desired size (in bytes) e.g. for 512 Kbytes use 512*1024